# Request specs for javascript failing, devise authentication

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test an action on a web application that requires authentication (through Devise). The specific action uses javascript, so I'm applying the `js` option to the spec as such:

```
scenario "User wants to fax a single document", js: true do
  reset_email
  @doc = @user.documents.create(FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:document))
  visit "/documents/#{@user.id}"

  click_on "send_document_#{@doc.id}"
  last_email.should eq(@doc)
end
```

The controller sends faxes in a email-ish way. I'm not sure why; I didn't write it. Regardless, at the top of this feature spec (using Capybara with Rspec), I authenticate using

```
before(:each) do
  # Signs in as an admin
  @company = FactoryGirl.create(:company)
  @subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_subscription, company_id: @company.id)
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, company_id: @company.id)
  login_as @user, scope: :user
end
```

All other specs in the file (which also require the login) still pass, which has me thinking it has to do with the javascript. So, the `js` option opens up a browser in Firefox, and the page is not the right content. It says

```
500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `status' for nil:NilClass
```

I've searched online and found only responses saying not to have actions in my controller called `response` or `action`. Rest assured, I have no actions as such; only RESTful actions along with two additionals:

```
def send_document
  @to = params[:to].gsub(/([() \-]+)/, '')
  #The below parses the number to format it for InterFax
  #It adds a "+1" to the front, and a dash in the middle 
  #of the number where needed.
  @to = "+1"+@to[0..-5]+"-"+@to[-4,4]
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  DocumentMailer.send_document(@to, @document).deliver
  render :template => false, :text => 'true'
end
def email_document
  @to = params[:to]
  @document = Document.find(params[:id])
  DocumentMailer.email_document(@to, @document).deliver
  render :template => false, :text => 'true'
end
```

Can anyone help make sense of these errors? A lot of this application uses javascript, and I really need a way to test those actions while being signed in.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful about checking for non-UI conditions without first testing that the action has completed. When you do:

```
  click_on "send_document_#{@doc.id}"
  last_email.should eq(@doc)
```

remember that the javascript is running inside a browser instance, which is not in the same process as your test code. It may help to check for an update on the page before moving on:

```
  click_on "send_document_#{@doc.id}"
  page.should have_content("Email sent") # for example
  last_email.should eq(@doc)
```

Capybara claims to be pretty smart about waiting for page elements to be visible - YMMV.

If your app requires a login, your request spec should use the normal login process -- visit the login page, type in credentials, then navigate to the page to test.